# How to change the number of items per row in products grid?

Tags: product-grid, magento-2.1

How to modify magento 2 to show 3 items per row in product grid instead of the default 4?

I tried to play with `/var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Catalog/web/css/source/module/_listings.less` but nothing changed.

I've restarted apache2... I have flushed magento2 cache ... I have deleted all folders under `/magento2/var/cache` ... but still showing 4 items per row!!!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I used CSS trick to change the number of appearances in a row

I just widened the li product-item and this worked for me.

```
>ol.product-items{
    >li.product-item{
        border:@border-1;
        width: 45%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `width:31.439%` for li tag with class name : item product product-item

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that Magento defines the number of product/row in their css by having a width defined. The only way to adjust that is to overwrite that line of css within your **app/designit/vendor/theme/web/css/source/_theme.less**

If you want to link that to a setting in your backend i'm afraid you are limited to inline css.

The answer from **sriharsha C R** is a good starting point even though i highly recommend of overwrite the whole .phtml fille and add a new class to that part of the html and add that class in your **app/designit/vendor/theme/web/css/source/_extend.less** with your own width to assure if they change the class names it will still work.